# id returned 1 exit status Código C, ajuda

Tags: c

meu código esta dando erro id returned 1 e não tenho a minima ideia por que esta dando este erro fiz tudo certinho, alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

  int main ()
  {
    float CP,LP,PP,LA,AA,PL,PC,FP,AT,QA,AAZ;
    Printf ("\nApresente o comprimento,Largura e profundidade: ");
    scanf ("%f, %f, %f", &CP, &LP, &PP);
    printf ("\napresente largura e altura do azulejo: ");
    scanf ("%f, %f", &LA, &AA);
    {
        PL = 2*CP*PP;
        PC = 2*LP*PP;
        FP = CP*LP;
        AT = PL+PC+FP;
        AAZ = LA*AA;
    }
    {
        QA = (AT / AAZ)*1.05;
    }
      printf("\nA quantidade de azulejos para o revestimento da piscina e: %f", QA);
     system ("PAUSE");
  }
```

Comment: Olá Matheus. Por favor, edite a sua pergunta para incluir uma explicação de qual é a sua dúvida.

Comment: sim já editei ,desculpa.

Comment: No http://ideone.com/aLP1dC funciona certinho. Passei as variaveis a `double` (nao ha razao para usar `float`) e tirei o `system("PAUSE");`

Comment: Onda tá `Printf` é `printf`.

Comment: Tá faltando a função `main` retornar algum valor também, não?

Comment: `id`? Não será `ld` (linker)?

Comment: Acho que é o id do erro. O GCC aqui retornou status 1, quando rodo esse código.

Comment: era mesma ai pra não editar e causar outro problema criei outra pergunta, mais consegui solucionar o problema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compilei o seu código na minha maquina e a mensagem de erro é bastante clara:

```
/tmp/ccaHCVvZ.o: In function `main':
a.c:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `Printf'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Ele não consegue achar uma definição para a função `Printf`. Você quer `printf`, não?

Habilitando warnings com a flag de compilação `-Wall` (sempre use) o erro fica ainda melhor:

```
a.c: In function ‘main’:
a.c:7:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘Printf’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     Printf ("\nApresente o comprimento,Largura e profundidade: ");
     ^
a.c:23:3: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
   }
   ^
/tmp/ccJtM9Fv.o: In function `main':
a.c:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `Printf'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Aqui é apontado (literalmente) a função que não existe. Além disso um segundo alerta é acusado: você definiu a função `main` para retornar `int`, mas não está retornando coisa alguma! Adicione um `return 0;` no final.