# Erro de referência indefinida - Allegro 5

Tags: c, c++, allegro

Instalei a lib [Allegro 5](https://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Getting_Started) com o seguinte script :

```
cd ~/Documentos

sudo apt install -y git build-essential subversion cmake xorg-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglu-dev install libpng-dev libz-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev libfreetype6-dev libjpeg-dev libvorbis-dev libopenal-dev libphysfs-dev libgtk2.0-dev libasound-dev libflac-dev libdumb1-dev install exuberant-ctags dvi2ps dvipdfmx latex2html pandoc

git clone https://github.com/liballeg/allegro5.git allegro

sudo mv ~/Documentos/allegro /opt

cd /opt/allegro && cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr .

make

sudo make install
```

Entao criei um arquivo `.c`, importei a lib e compilei o código com os seguintes comandos : `gcc -Wall -Wextra teste.c -o Test` e `gcc -lallegro -Wall -Wextra teste.c -o Test`, recebi o seguinte output :

```
/tmp/ccnmnCzr.o: na função `main':
teste.c:(.text+0x1c): referência indefinida para `al_create_display'
teste.c:(.text+0x34): referência indefinida para `al_map_rgb'
teste.c:(.text+0x61): referência indefinida para `al_clear_to_color'
teste.c:(.text+0x66): referência indefinida para `al_flip_display'
teste.c:(.text+0x7b): referência indefinida para `al_rest'
teste.c:(.text+0x87): referência indefinida para `al_destroy_display'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Alguém sabe como resolver, pesquisei e encontrei respostas como : [Returned 1 exit status - Código C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14136/id-returned-1-exit-status-c%C3%B3digo-c-ajuda) indicando correção de erro de syntax, [What does “ collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status ” mean ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272525/what-does-collect2-error-ld-returned-1-exit-status-mean/27272651)
 indicando um possível erro no processo de compilação dentre outras perguntas que não deixaram claro como resolver, neste contexto de Allegro 5.

Códigos que utilizei para testar :

```
# include <stdio.h>

# include <allegro5/allegro.h>

int main(){ // Este exemplo roda sem erros !

    return 0;

}
```

E este [exemplo](https://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Allegro_5_Tutorial/Displays) da própria Allegro ( Este é o exemplo que gera o erro mencionado acima ).

**Obs** : Todos os programas, libs ... estão atualizados, reiniciei o computador e testei outros exemplos, mas continua na mesma.

Comment: O Ubuntu tem /usr/lib32 ou /usr/lib64?

Comment: Esse erro acontece caso o GCC não encontra as libraries do Allegro. Normalmente isso ocorre em Linux's que por padrão instala as libraries em /usr/lib64. Você tem que modificar o LIBDIR do processo de compilação para /usr/lib64, porque normalmente pode instalar no diretório com as libs 32 bits. Verifica se esse é o teu caso, por favor.

Comment: Nenhuma das duas opções que tu indicou, i.imgur.com/hpjWma1.png, apenas lib ... o processo seria o mesmo, digo de modificar o Lib Dir ?

Comment: então tua máquina é 32 bits? Ou melhor teu Linux é 32bits?

Comment: A máquina é 64 / 86 ( I.imgur.com/hFgxO6N.png ) e a distribuição é Ubuntu Budgie 64 Bits ( 17.10 )

Comment: Sei que deveríamos estar no chat, mas executa ```find /usr -iname 'liballegro*'```, e vai dar para ver onde instalou. Não consigo ver as imagens porque estou atrás de um firewall.

Comment: Eu vou usar o chat. Vou te chamar lá. E depois eu publico uma resposta.

Comment: Tranquilo, as imagens são só uma confirmação para oque eu estou falando em texto **^ - ^**. A maioria está em `/usr/lib/liballegro_*.so` , `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/*` e `/usr/share/doc/liballegro*.so`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71855/discussion-between-lemoce-and-walter).